# Image Magick animating images

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, animated-gif

Hello people here is my code below...

```
        $_FILES=array();
        $GIF = new Imagick();
        $GIF->setFormat("gif");

        $_FILES['image0']="C:\wamp\www\latest\im\image0.gif";
        $_FILES['image1']="C:\wamp\www\latest\im\image1.gif";
        $_FILES['image2']="C:\wamp\www\latest\im\image2.gif";
        $_FILES['image3']="C:\wamp\www\latest\im\image3.gif";



        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES); ++$i) {


            $frame = new Imagick();
            $frame->readImage($_FILES["image$i"]);
            $frame->setImageDelay(100);
            $GIF->addImage($frame);
        }

        $GIF->writeImages("C:\wamp\www\latest\im\allimage.gif" , true);
```

above code works fine by creating an Animated gif, But the problem is it overlaps on the previous images,,,Iam trying to `disappear the previous image` when the next image comes... something like `Timer` ,... is there a way to fix this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [setImageDispose](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedispose.php) method to clear the frame area:

```php
$frame->readImage($_FILES["image$i"]);
$frame->setImageDispose(2);
$frame->setImageDelay(100);
```

- Undefined: 0 -> No disposal specified (equivalent to 'none').
- None: 1 -> Do not dispose, just overlay next frame image.
- Background: 2 -> Clear the frame area with the background color.
- Previous: 3 -> Clear to the image prior to this frames overlay.

And you could add a call to '[optimizeImageLayers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.optimizeimagelayers.php)' to reduce the size of your file:

```
$GIF->optimizeImageLayers();
$GIF->writeImages("C:\wamp\www\latest\im\allimage.gif" , true);
```